# Can someone help me numerically integrate some integrals involving quotient and $\sin(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, math-software, numerical-calculus

I am trying to numerically integrate the following integrals ($*$ is multiplication symbol):

(1) $$
\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\sin(\pi y) - \sin(\pi x)}{y - x}*\dfrac{(\sin(\pi x)*y - \sin(\pi y)*x)}{y - x}$$

over $x \in [-1, 1], y \in [-1, 1]$

I tried to punching [this integral into Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22(1%2F4)*((sin(pi%20y)%20-%20sin(pi%20x))%2F(y%20-%20x))*((sin(pi%20x)*y%20-%20sin(pi%20y)*x)%2F(y%20-%20x))%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22double%20integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22,%20%22dflt%22%7D), but I received a time out error

and

(2) $$\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)*y - \sin(\pi y)*x}{y - x}$$

over $x \in [-1, 1], y \in [-1, 1]$

I also tried punching [this into Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22(1%2F4)*((sin(pi%20x)*y%20-%20sin(pi%20y)*x)%2F(y%20-%20x))%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22double%20integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22,%20%22dflt%22%7D) but I also received a time out error

Can someone please help me integrating these functions? I am certain that they are supposed to have solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integrals are $0$, by the symmetry $x\to -x$, $y \to -y$.

If you insist on doing it numerically, Maple can do it:

> evalf(Int(1/4*(sin(Pi * y)-sin(Pi * x))/(y-x) * (sin(Pi * x) * y - sin(Pi * y) * x)/(y-x),[x=-1..1,y=-1..1]));

$$ 0.$$

> evalf(Int((sin(Pi * x) * y-sin(Pi * y) * x)/(x-y),[x=-1..1,y=-1..1]));

$$ 0. $$

Comment: Thanks. So there is something that says if $f(x,y) = f(-x,-y)$, therefore $\int\int f(x,y) dxdy = 0$?

Comment: No, $f(x,y) = -f(-x,-y)$, and you are integrating over a region that is invariant under this symmetry.